# ConTeXt: vertical alignment besides table

Tags: tables, floats, context

I want to place a table besides some text:

```
\starttext
  \placetable[left,none]{}{%
    \starttable[|l|]
      \HL \VL Test \VL \SR \HL
    \stoptable
  }

  Here be some text
\stoptext
```

This does not look very nice, because the table starts somewhat below the text:

[image]

Inserting `\blank[2cm]` before the text does not seem to do anything. How can I have the table start at the same vertical position as the text?

Comment: Try `\blank[2cm,force]` to make that solution work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not need to have it aligned exactly with the baseline of the text, just add a negative multiple of `line` in the `location` key.  My personal advice is to always use the `\start...\stop` interface, also for `placetable`.  Furthermore, I recommend using Natural Tables.

```
\starttext
\startplacetable
  [
    location={left,none,-line},
  ]
  \startTABLE
    \NC Test \NC\NR
  \stopTABLE
\stopplacetable
Here be some text
\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: You can use the `high` keyword to get rid of the space before the float, this positions the content a bit lower than your solution with `-line`.

Comment: I must admit that I don't like this solution, but it's difficult to come up with a better proposal as the question is a bit vague. If the table and the text next to it must stay together, a float doesn't seem the best solution (because it, um, floats). And what does "the same vertical position as the text" mean for a table? The baseline of the first row is identical? Or of the last row? Or the text is in the middle of the table height? My instinct would be to use a combination or frames within frames, but the question has to be clarified.

Comment: I agree that I did not specify exactly what I wanted, but this seems to be a good solution. I already tried using paragraphs, but that did not work with the formula I had in the text besides the table. The problem with using paragraphs (or columns) is that I need to specify their width in advance rather than letting the table decide its width.

Answer (score 0):

Given the simplicity, I hope I understood the question correctly.
Why don't you use the `cline` command ? Is the following what you expect ?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|l}
        \cline{1-1}
        Test & Here be some text\\
        \cline{1-1}
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well firstly, the question was about ConTeXt, not LaTeX. Second, my example was minimal. The actual table has many rows and the text besides it many paragraphs, which makes your solution not suitable.

Comment: Well, I guess "no" I did not understand the question :) `minipage` environment  sometimes helps in LaTeX, is there any equivalent in ConTeXt ?